# duplicate ID error inflating fragment, android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, runtime-error

I have a fragment class, fragment1, with the following code:

```java
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private TextView bunz_count;
    private TextView money_count;
    private Bunz bunz;
    private Handler handler;
    int delay = 1000;
    View view;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        bunz = Bunz.getInstance();
        handler = new Handler();


            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
            bunz_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.final_bunz_count);
            money_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.final_money_count);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                update(view);
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);







        return view;
    }
```

this works fine for activities that implement onCreate(), but for activities that implement onResume(), I get an Inflation error, due to a duplicate ID.

For instance, the fragment code in my mainActivity XML file looks like the following:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment14"
        android:name="com.example.bunzclicker.fragment1"
        android:layout_width="371dp"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.375"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.013"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment1" />
```

and when I go to this activity, go to another activity, and go back to this activity, I get an inflation error, with the following lines of code in the java from my main activity class:

```java
protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I know this has something to do with duplicate IDs, since the fragment is already initialized and you can't create another one, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't call `setContentView()` in `onResume()`. That should normally happen only once, in `onCreate()`. The `onResume()` might be called many times during the `Activity`'s lifetime.

Comment: ah, got it thanks!